# independent binomial variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$X$ and $Y$ be 2 independent bi variableswith parameters $n$ and $p=\frac12$. Is $P(X-Y=0)$ equal to this? Since ${X-Y=0}$ , then the events $X$ and $Y$ are equal, $X=Y$ then the event, $P(X-Y=0)$ equals to: $$P (\bigcup_{k=o}^n (X=k, Y=k) = \sum_{k=o}^n P(X=k, Y=k)=\sum_{k=o}^n P(X=k)P(Y=k)=\sum_{k=o}^n {n \choose k}\left(\frac12\right)^k \left(\frac12\right)^{n-k} {n \choose k}\left(\frac12\right)^k\left(\frac12\right)^{n-k}=\sum_{k=o}^n {n \choose k}\left(\frac12\right)^n {n \choose k}\left(\frac12\right)^n$$. How to simplify this one? Thanks I am stuck with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By symmetry the binomial coefficients part is $\sum_0^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}$. This sum is $\binom{2n}{n}$.

To see that, suppose we have a box of $n$ distinct doughnuts and a box of $n$ distinct muffins, and want to choose a snack of $n$ items. This can be done in $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways.

But it can also be done in $\sum_0^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}$ ways, for that counts the ways we can pick, for any $k$, $k$ doughnuts and the rest muffins.

**Another way:** The random variable $X+Y$ has binomial distribution, for $X+Y$ is the number of "successes" in $2n$ independent trials, where the probability of success on any trial is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Note now that for any $k$, the probability that Alicia  gets $k$ heads and Beti gets $k$ heads is the same as the probability that Alicia gets $k$ heads and Beti gets $k$ tails, that is, the total number of heads between them is $n$.

We have just shown that $\Pr(X=Y)=\Pr(X+Y=n)$. This probability is $\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}$.

Comment: got it thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome. The usual combinatorial argument has $n$ men and $n$ women, and we want to choose a committee of $n$ people. But that's too bureaucratic for my taste, and anyway I am hungry.

Comment: Are you sure this is what the question is asking? What is the relationship between what you said and the condition where $X=Y$ ? You seem to be talking about $X+Y=N$

Comment: @fodon: Yes, quite sure. But you are right! As was pointed out in the analysis by OP, the probability that $X=Y$ is $\sum \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{k}2^{-2n}$. But by the symmetry of the Pascal Triangle, we have $\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n}{n-k}$. So the sum is $\sum \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{n-k}2^{-2n}$. And this is clearly the probability that $X+Y=n$. This probability is $\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n}$.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that

$\frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k}^2$

Comment: How can I simplify this, $\sum_{k=0}^n  {n \choose k}^2$